# Payday 2 WINE problems

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, keyboard, wine, games

So I'm wanting to play Payday 2. Which I do successfully but I have some problems. The first one is that when I try to type something in chat it crashes and exits the game. I type the message into the box, click enter and BOOM it crashes. The second problem is that sometimes when I'm playing I lose keyboard control and can't play with the keyboard. So I then can't ALT + TAB out of the game or press ESC to exit the game. I'm stuck there of which I'm then kicked from the game because I can't get to the finish. These problems happen quite frequently and I don't know how to fix them. Any help is MUCH appreciated. I have Xubuntu.